# Value not increasing in table in while clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and when I clicked on leftmost column's number like **1,2,3...** I want their respective rightmost column **0** to increase like **1,2,3,4,5..**.(Increase by 1 on every click.)

```js
var ms=document.getElementById('message');
        window.onload = build;
        var myArray = ["Laurence", "Mike", "John", "Larry", "Kim", "Joanne", "Lisa", "Janet", "Jane"];
        var message = document.getElementById('message');

        function build() {
            var html = "<h1>My Friends Table</h1><table>";
            for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
                html += '<tr data-row="' + x + '" data-vote="0"><td class="box" >' + (x + 1) + '</td><td>' + myArray[x] + '</td><td>0</td></tr>';
            }
            html += '</table>';
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
            var elbox = document.querySelectorAll('#output .box');
            var a;
            var v;
            for (var x = 0; x < elbox.length; x++) {
               
                elbox[x].onclick = function () {
                    
                   console.dir(this);
                
                    a = this.closest('[data-row]').getAttribute('data-row');
         
                    console.log(myArray[a]);
                    message.innerHTML = myArray[a] + " is on row #" + a;
                    v = this.closest('[data-vote]').getAttribute('data-vote');
                    v++;
                    console.log(v);
                 this.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerText=v;
               
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
   td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Complete JavaScript Course</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="message">Complete JavaScript Course</div>
    <div id="output"></div>
   
</body>

</html>
```

I have set v++ but why the value of v is not increasing? I am still seeing value as `1`. To update the innertext,I have used

```
  this.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerText=v;
```

Since `<tr>` is parent of `td` and i used  `this.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerText=v;` why its just stuck to `1` on every click?Why it is not increasing after one?

Comment: Attribute values are strings.  `getAttribute` is going to return the value of the data attribute as a string, not a number.  Open your developer tools, go to your console and type this: `var x = "1"; x++;`

Comment: I tried again creating like this:  p=parseInt(v)+1;
                   
                 this.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerText=p;  but it is still not working

Comment: All of your `data-vote` are zero.  `0 + 1` is 1.

Comment: but i have updated the data-vote using this.parentElement.lastElementChild.innerText=v; why isnt the innertext being updated?

Comment: Sure you're updating the inner text.  You are not updating the data-vote

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click it is based on data-vote attribute value of the first td of the row.

You do modify the innerText of the right column but after that you should do something like this to modify the data-vote attribute also:

```
this.parentElement.firstElementChild.dataset.vote=v;
```

Comment: if it is so,then what is the use of .innettext here I am using? We used to update the DOM using .innerText previously.

Comment: If you want to use .innerText only : v = this.closest('[data-vote]').getAttribute('data-vote');       v must take the value from the inner text parsed to integer value not from data-vote attribute value otherwise you must modify the data-vote also